# How to show HTML content in TextBlock using XAML from UWP app?

Tags: html, xaml, uwp

In JSON response:

```
results =  "<p>This is a <b>paragraph</b></p><p>New paragraph with symbols &gt; tags</p>";
```

XAML:

```
<Textblock  Text={Binding results}/>
```

result:

```
This is a **paragraph** New Word
New paragraph with symbols > tags
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RichTextBlock` to more easily match HTML DOM with XAML output. Unfortunately, there is not built-in API that will transform HTML into equivalent XAML for the control.

You can parse the HTML into known tags using `HtmlAgilityPack` and add items into `RichTextBlock.Inlines` manually. There is an old [Docs article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/tess/displaying-html-content-in-a-richtextblock) on this process, but it still applies. One of the examples it shows:

```
private static Inline GenerateBlockForNode(HtmlNode node)
{
    switch (node.Name)
    {
        case "div":
            return GenerateSpan(node);
        case "p":
        case "P":
            return GenerateInnerParagraph(node);
        case "img":
        case "IMG":
            return GenerateImage(node);
        ...
```

The individual `GenerateXXX` methods then generate appropriate inlines:

```
private static Inline GenerateSpan(HtmlNode node)
{
    Span s = new Span();
    AddChildren(s, node);
    return s;
}
```

The easiest solution would be to use the code in [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/xleon/HTML2XAML), which implements a lot the tag conversion and maybe you will be able to just copy-paste the converter to your project and get running.

Comment: This one is not supported for me

Comment: is any way to use html tag elements in xaml for UWP app?

Comment: @umaraja Which part of it is not supported? Unfortunately HTML cannot be used directly (if you don't want to just display a WebView)

Comment: <b>Bold</b> tag is not supported

Comment: string html = "<p>hi this is the <b>new</b> line&nbsp;<br />second line</p> <p>third <b>line</b></p>";
    var Data = Windows.Data.Html.HtmlUtilities.ConvertToText(html); ;

Comment: The above one is working however bold is not working

Comment: <b> Tag should definitely be supported - see https://github.com/xleon/HTML2XAML/blob/b835f9ce24546a06131bb0ecd3c9a8850460cdc2/XAMLHtml/XAMLHtml.cs#L157 , have you tried including the cs file to your project? Which input does it fail on for you? ConvertToText only removes the tags, so it cannot preserve formatting.

Comment: I used <webview  x:Name = webview/> .It resolved my problem